# How to create a plug-in for Windows Mobile web browser (IE) using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, browser, mobile, plugins

I  have a plug in for IE created in .NET C# now I want to port it to IE for Win mobile (5, 6, 7) how to do such thing?  (I mean a plug in like Flash for example...) ( I vant to see some kind of special visual element on the page that appeare when some special tag appeares in html document... like  bla bla bla )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLR Hosting isn't supported with the Compact Framework, and without that, you can't load a managed assembly into an unmanaged program (Such as IE)

I can't find a good citation from MSDN, but it is mentioned here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/8e6946af-62ed-4c3e-99c3-921c725a76a9

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=175) describes a plug-in written in C++. Maybe it is useful to get started (it has some presentation links) and then link this knowledge with the COM Interop features of the .NET compact framework [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446497.aspx)

Comment: actualy I ment - I vant to see some kind of special visual element on the page that appeare when some special tag appeares in html document... like <myPlugin> bla bla bla </myPlugin>